# What's wrong with the global variable declaration in following code?

Tags: php, global-variables

Here is a small snippet from my code:

```
<?php   
  set_time_limit(0);


  require_once("../../includes/application-header.php");
  require_once OCN_ROOT."/core/extention/pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd_config.php";
  require_once OCN_ROOT."/core/extention/pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd.php";

  global $active_p_tag = true;

try
{   
    //Do something
}
catch($why)
{
    //catch something
}
?>
```

For the above code I'm getting an error as follows:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in pdf_test_question_paper.php on line 9
```

I'm not getting what's going wrong here. Can any one help me in correcting the issue please?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign values when declaring variables global. `global` does not make variable global, it imports variable from the global scope. It operates on variables, not expressions.

Comment: Ok,then how should I assign value to this variable?

Comment: Just take out `global`.  You use `global` before the name if you want to refer to it in a different scope, like in a function.

Answer (score 0):

global keyword is used for setting scope for global variables. 
No need for the global keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try after Removing `global` Keyword

```
<?php   
  set_time_limit(0);
  $active_p_tag = true;    

  require_once("../../includes/application-header.php");
  require_once OCN_ROOT."/core/extention/pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd_config.php";
  require_once OCN_ROOT."/core/extention/pdfcrowd/pdfcrowd.php";

try
{   
    //Do something
}
catch($why)
{
    //catch something
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a global var, you have to separate the global var declaration from the attribution:

```
global $active_p_tag;
$active_p_tag = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this: [PHP GLOBAL VARIABLES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)
for example :

- assign:$GLOBAL['foo'] = true;
- read: $GLOBAL['foo']